# Open Youtube video in a new window?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following html to embed youtube window in page,

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" width="320" height="190"></iframe>
```

Is it possible that when I click the play, it should redirect me to the youtube page.

Comment: use javascript window.open()

Comment: window.location on js onclick

Comment: @ManigandanArjunan, can you provide a sample on Fiddler.

Comment: @NewBee, can you provide a sample?

Comment: Youtube player already have a button to open the video in youtube. So you just want to display the thumbnail of the video and always open it in youtube?

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe, I need to open in a new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use another `div` to cover the real `iframe` element. So when user click on the place they think the `iframe`, the `div` `onclick` event is fired.

You can see a demo here http://jsbin.com/uhajun/2/edit